# jsoup hasClass returns wrong result

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Help me please. I using a jsoup lib and its method `hasClass`. Why `Cur` returns "none!"? The source page:

```
<body>
<div class="pagenav" data-role="vbpagenav" data-pagenumber="2" data-totalpages="223" data-address="showthread.php?t=650495&amp;page=102" data-address2="" data-anchor="">
</div>
</body>
```

My code:

```
Document doc = null;
String result = "";
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
    Elements body = doc.select("body");

    /* Navigation */
    String Cur = "";
    if (body.hasClass("pagenav")) {
        Elements Current = body.select("div[data-pagenumber]");
        String Cur1 = Current.attr("data-pagenumber");
        int cur_page = Integer.parseInt(Cur1);
        int next_page = cur_page + 1;
        Cur = Integer.toString(next_page);
    } else {
        Cur = "none!";
    }

    result = body.html() + Cur;

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the method `hasClass` the wrong way.

In your selection you create a collection `Elements body` that contains all the `body` tags as `Element` objects.

```
public boolean hasClass(String className)
```

will return a `true` or `false` as to whether any of your Element objects in your Elements body have the class name in their class attribute. Here you will see what is wrong, since your collection `Elements body` only contains all the `body` tags, and not their child nodes. None of your `body` tags have their class attribute set to `pagenav`, thus the `hasClass()` method will return `false`.

---

To solve your problem, you will need to create a new collection `Elements` object for all the child nodes of the `body` tags, and then check whether or not they have the class attribute set to `pagenav`.

Selecting the body tag your way would require a double loop, such as

```
    Elements body = doc.select("body");
    Elements bodyChildren = new Elements();
    for (Element e : body) {
        for (Element eChild : e.children()) {
            bodyChildren.add(eChild);
        }
    }

    if (bodyChildren.hasClass("pagenav")){...
```

Though, since you can only have one body tag, it can be more effective to select it straight away as follows

```
    Element body = doc.select("body").first();
    Elements bodyChildren = new Elements();
    for (Element e : body.children()) {
        bodyChildren.add(e);
    }
```

Both of above methods will return `true` when you run `hasClass()` on `bodyChildren`.